# How to present proof of reCaptcha solving

Tags: node.js, recaptcha, blockchain

This is a weird question but it's completely valid, and I'm really out of ideas so maybe you guys could lend me a neuron or two?

I'm implementing a trustless blockchain service. Users need to solve captchas that are validated with Google by a central server. For most web apps this would be enough. But this is decentralized, so... For my web app the server also needs to present proof they actually solved the captcha (that the server didn't just make up "yeah this user solved a captcha" when they didn't).

I thought that the server could make public the user's response token, but others still wouldn't be able to re-verify that the response token was actually valid. And to my knowledge, there is no field that relates a response token with google's true/false response for that particular request.

Any ideas on how could I implement such a thing?

Thank you very much!